# How to add dynamic banners inside the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

i have one `UITableview`, i want to add some banner images on that `UITableview`,its dynamic banners,not specific row may be after 3 or 2 or 5 etc the banner want to show is it possible please help me

Thank you in advance

Comment: Show me the code..

Answer (score 0):

In general you can do it like that:

Store indexes of the rows, which should hold banners, in an array in some way

```
NSArray *bannerIndexArray = @[@2, @3, @5];
```

Put banners into cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // set banner in each cell to nil in some way ...

    for (NSNumber *rowIndex in bannerIndexArray) {
        if ([rowIndex integerValue] == indexPath.row) {
            // insert banner into cell ...
            break;
        }

    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i have to implement same situvations someone please help me to do this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Have a look at `UITableViewDataSource`, the doku is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html)

Especially look at `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Through this method you determine the content of the table view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this JScrollView_PageControl_AutoScroll in tableViewCell as i have used it one of my projects and it is very easy implement and useful.
https://github.com/jacobjiangwei/JScrollView_PageControl_AutoScroll